# ERROR: After installing NVIDIA Driver on Ubuntu (22.04.3 LTS)

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I tried to install `nvidia-driver-535` on my Acer Swift laptop running Ubuntu (22.04.3 LTS) having mx250 nvidia graphic card. After installing it, during the boot time I got this error and I was not able to login normally.

[image: error]

To resolve that, I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and I purged nvidia and I did reboot which helped me boot normally.

How can I install nvidia driver again and overcome that error.

Comment: Please go back to nvidia driver-525. You can do it with `sudo software-properties-gtk` and the GUI will pop up. Select the `Additional Drivers` tab and choose the 525 driver. Once it has downloaded and unpacked, `sudo reboot`.